# OCaml typesystem unintended nesting

Tags: ocaml, type-inference, algebraic-data-types

In an OCaml toplevel, I have the following type definition:

```
type 'a lazy_list =
| Nil
| Cons of 'a * 'a lazy_list
| LazyCons of 'a * 'a lazy_list
```

(Simplified for this example)

And this function definition:

```
let head = function
| Nil -> Nil
| Cons(x,_) | LazyCons(x,_) -> x
```

The ocaml toplevel tells me the type of `head` is `'a lazy_list lazy_list -> 'a lazylist` Why is the type not `'a lazy_list -> 'a`, which is what I would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible result of your function is `Nil`. `Nil` is a `lazy_list`. Therefore the result type of `head` must be a `t lazy_list` for some (or possibly all) types `t`.

The other possible result of `head` is `x` where `x` is an element of the given list. Therefore the result type of `head` must be the element type of the given list.

By combining these two pieces of information we can conclude that the element type of the given list must itself be a list. Therefore your function can only operate on lists of lists.

If the type of `head` were merely `'a laty_list -> 'a`, `Nil` would not be valid result for it.